# Renaming column and index values one expression

Tags: python, pandas, naming

I'm not sure why this code isn't working. If I define `tankwater.columns =`  or `tankwater.index =`  expressions separatly the columns and index are renamed,  but when I try and combine them using the rename function I get "list object is not callable."

It's probably something simple.. Thanks in advance.

`tankwater = tankwater.rename(index = ['Date 1', 'Date 2'], columns = ['Tank1','Tank 2', 'Tank 3', 'Total water'])`

Comment: _"f I do each expression separate the columns and index are renamed"_ - really? I try `df.rename(columns=['a','b','c','d'])` on a small dataframe with 4 columns and it throws the exact same error.

Comment: Do you need to use `tankwater.set_axis()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dicts instead of lists where the keys are the old values and the items the new ones. Like so:

```py
tankwater = tankwater.rename(index = {'oldindex1':'Date 1',
                                      'oldindex2':'Date 2'},
                             columns = {'oldcolumn1': 'Tank1',
                                        'oldcolumn2': 'Tank 2',
                                        'oldcolumn3': 'Tank 3',
                                        'oldcolumn4': 'Total water'})
```

Added code for easier use for the example provided:

```py
tankwater = tankwater.rename(index = dict(zip(tankwater.index, ['Date 1', 'Date 2'])),
                             columns = dict(zip(tankwater.columns, ['Tank1','Tank 2', 'Tank 3', 'Total water'])))
```

Where old indexes and old columns are the names to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks, that works as well. I was thinking that there was an easier way without having to call out the columns and indexs that hadn't been named already. Thanks!

Comment: yeah np you could do something like `dict(zip(tankwater.index, ['Date 1', 'Date 2']))`  and `dict(zip(tankwater.columns, ['Tank1','Tank 2', 'Tank 3', 'Total water']))` but I don't see much more that could be done

Comment: Oops! @Mario you edited your answer just before I posted my, and they're now nearly identical... :D

Comment: @richardec Haha! I just saw it! Amazing that we came to the same exact conclusion!

Answer (score 1):

You must use a `dict` containing the old column/index labels and the new ones, but you can use `dict` + `zip` to do it dynamically:

```
tankwater = tankwater.rename(
    index=dict(zip(tankwater.index, ['Date 1', 'Date 2'])),
    columns=dict(zip(tankwater.columns, ['Tank1','Tank 2', 'Tank 3', 'Total water']))
)
```